# Android start a timer/clock

Tags: android, sql, time, clock, execute

Hy ,

I have to make a aplication on Android to verify the time of 2 types of databases (SQLite , MySQL) , so i need to make an "clock" or something like that to start a time , execute an sql operation and then stop it and take the time.
   How can i make it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) or [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).